# jQuery setInterval for next element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a working html code here:

```
<div class="monitoring-icons">
    <div class="mon-img hovicon effect-1 sub-a mon-active">
    <img class="icon-active" src="http://placehold.it/125X125&text=Blood" width="100px" data-info="blood">
    </div>

    <div class="mon-img hovicon effect-1 sub-a">
    <img class="icon-inactive" src="http://placehold.it/125X125&text=Weight" width="100px" data-info="weight">
    </div>

    <div class="mon-img hovicon effect-1 sub-a">
    <img class="icon-inactive" src="http://placehold.it/125X125&text=Sleep" width="100px" data-info="sleep">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="monitoring-infor">

<div class="icon-item" id="info-blood">
<h2 class="smaller">Blood Pressure</h2>
<p>Etiam sed velit hendrerit, facilisis est sit amet, facilisis orci. Vestibulum et risus condimentum, tristique purus sit amet, placerat sem. Ut blandit lorem id sem iaculis, et consequat lorem vestibulum. </p>
</div>

<div class="icon-item monitoring-info-item" id="info-weight">
<h2 class="smaller">Weight </h2>
<p>Cras malesuada lacinia libero a maximus. Cras ullamcorper tellus in ante laoreet eleifend. Donec tincidunt libero nec tellus placerat pretium.</p>
</div>


<div class="icon-item monitoring-info-item" id="info-sleep">
<h2 class="smaller">Sleep </h2>
<p>Fusce nunc arcu, ultrices vel odio at, vulputate pulvinar nunc. Sed placerat, lorem ac consequat lobortis, turpis lacus interdum nibh, vel ultricies urna felis vel neque. Nunc pharetra laoreet ante, eu pulvinar est. Nullam sollicitudin ultricies enim at aliquet. Nulla pharetra nulla in sem viverra consectetur. Fusce quis turpis tristique, hendrerit neque ut, facilisis eros.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to go to the next `mon-img` and add `mon-active` and I have a successful jquery here:

```
setInterval(function(){                
        $('.mon-active').removeClass(function(){
            $(this).next().addClass('mon-active');
            return 'mon-active';
            $(this+'img').trigger('click');
        }); 
    }, 10000);
```

Its working but what I wanted is to loop it. When its the last mon-img then I wanted it to add the css `mon-active` to the first `mon-img`.

Also, at the same time I want to trigger `click` event so that the relevant information for the image button should be displayed.

here is [my complete code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpnimitz/5zLLmj9q/3/).

Comment: Please explain what behavior you want the three monitoring icons to perform. You say you want to add `mon-active`, but you aren't clear about the triggering event you want to attach that to.

Comment: Please include here the relevant parts of the fiddle link.

Comment: 'Mon-active' is just a css style, it only adds style to the next button... However, i also, wanted if the next button, where the monitoring items should also reveal the information related to it. I am using data-info on the button (image) and the data value is the id of the information related to the button

Comment: Hi guys, question is updated and clear some things what I really wanted to do. Thanks in advance if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to the whole code given in your fiddle. There are some points to note that will simplify the code.

1) The switching of class `mon-active` is done inside the click-handler of the images. There's no need to do it again in the interval: each time you trigger a click the class-switching is done automatically.

2) Don't create a jQuery-object with same selector multiple times. It's much to write and takes much time to execute. Create it once, store it in a variable and refer to it by the var name.

3) If you perform multiple actions on the same object use **chaining** of the actions.

So your code may look like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var timer = myInterval(), // EDIT
    delay;

// variables for often used jQuery objects:
var imgs = $('.monitoring-icons img'),
    mons = $('.mon-img'),
    info = $('.monitoring-infor div.icon-item');
// no need for '.each()', jQuery's '.on()' does the 'each' internally
imgs.on("click", function(ev, i){

    var ths = $(this), // 'this' refers to the clicked image
        par = ths.parent(), // get the parent div of the clicked image
        infoid = '#info-' + ths.data('info'), // get the associated id from data
        infoshow = $(infoid); // get the associated info-element with that id

    par.addClass('mon-active'); // make parent-div of clicked image active
    // use '.not()' to select all the other mon-divs that are not this parent
    mons.not(par).removeClass('mon-active'); // make all others inactive

    // here use chaining of two actions 'removeClass()' and 'addClass()'
    ths.removeClass('icon-inactive').addClass('icon-active'); // make clicked img active
    // '.not()' selects all imgs that are not this clicked image
    imgs.not(this).removeClass('icon-active').addClass('icon-inactive'); // make them inactive

    // do the same with the associated info-text-divs
    infoshow.removeClass('monitoring-info-item').addClass('mon-info');
    info.not(infoshow).removeClass('mon-info').addClass('monitoring-info-item');

    clearInterval(timer); clearTimeout(delay); // EDIT
    delay = setTimeout(function() {timer = myInterval();}, 20000); // EDIT

});

function myInterval() { // EDIT
    return setInterval(function(){ //EDIT: return added           
        var act = $('.mon-active'), // get the active div
            // get the index of active div and add one to have index of the next
            // with 'modulo' we get '0' when active is the last one, so we start from beginning
            i = (mons.index(act) + 1) % mons.length;
        // trigger the next image, all needed actions are done in the click-handler above
        imgs.eq(i).trigger('click');
    }, 10000);
} // EDIT

});
```

I hope this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zLLmj9q/58/) does all you want, otherwise please post critique.

**EDIT** According to your last question: 1) Define variables to hold the interval and delay on top of code. 2) Wrap setInterval in a function `myInterval()` that returns this interval. 3) Inside the click-handler add some code that stops the interval with `clearInterval()`, sets a delay of 20000ms with `setTimeout()`, then starts the Interval again by calling `myInterval()`. I've added the code above and marked it with `// EDIT`.

Comment: Thank you so much.... I am so new to jquery and i dont jave any experience in javascript...

Comment: @NimitzE. You're welcome. We all have been beginners.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on your code.. I'll be able to learn from it. I appreciate a lot. :)

Comment: But i still have one problem.. When you click it.. Two mon-active is present during interval.

Comment: @NimitzE. When you inspect the elements in your console (F12) you'll find only one `mon-active` and one `icon-active` at each time. The interval and each click do exactly the same: select one and make all others inactive. But when you **hover** over another element it becomes not active but gets a circle around. That's done by your CSS, it only *looks like active*.

Comment: Wow, I learn a lot from your code. Anyway, about my previous message, I was looking on my mobile phone, I guess the touch was still in effect which is hover effect in desktop thats why it was showing two `mon-active`. Thank you again @Martin, can't thank you enough :)

Comment: Last question martin, how if If its clicked, I wanna delay it with 30 seconds, how can I implement that, I believe it will be place inside `on`?

Comment: @NimitzE. Please see my EDIT. Now each time you click the interval stops and 30 seconds later starts again.